# What is this shrub with red stalks

Tags: identification

I have this shrub - during the season it has bright green leaves with a white outline and has red stalks

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a red twig dogwood shrub. The flowers are different than the dogwood trees that people think of when they hear dogwood. It's a shade-loving deciduous plant that averages 5 feet tall. I've found variegated varieties to be susceptible to fungus so watch for signs.

It's great for multi seasonal interest: spring flowers, cover for birds, variegation brightens up shaded areas, fall color, and finally winter color as well.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you live some where cold/north. It would be a red twig dogwood. They will grow farther north than Edmonton Canada. They also come in yellow. They like water, and can be invasive with the right conditions. They root readily from cuttings. The white-edged leaves is likely a developed hybrid.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely Cornus alba sibirica 'variegata', or possibly Cornus alba 'elegantissima'; both have red stems and similar variegated leaves.  The first one doesn't  get too huge, reaching usually between 5 and 6 feet tall and wide, but the second gets much larger; it can reach easily over 10 feet tall and wide.  If your plant has been in the ground for longer than 4 or 5 years, it's  more likely to be C. alba sibirica 'variegata', pictured  https://www.andre-briant.fr/en/variety-range/access-to-varieties/deciduous-shrubs/3845-cornus-alba-sibirica-variegata-.html

With either of these shrubs, if you want bright red stems during winter, it is advisable to prune back half the stems in spring as growth begins - it's only the newer stems that look bright red, they fade to a dull shade in their second and subsequent years.
Knowing where you are in the world and how long the pictured shrub has been planted for would be helpful for a more definite ID.... there are other possibilities.

Comment: My bad, I mistook it for cornus serica ; It looks small but i thought it was in a bad location. I grew a lot of serica when I lived along a stream in northern IL.

Comment: Well it might be C. serica 'White Gold' - depends how long it's been in, (hard to judge from size without knowing that) and the actual colour of the leaves.I'm just going by what we can see in the current image, along with the verbal description of leaf colour... and to some extent,where the OP is in the world...